# Byte array and Except()

Tags: c#

I have a problem with Except() C# and I don't understand why this issue happens at all.
For example I have array: `[ 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 9, 3 ]`

I use Except to cut out: [ 4, 6, 8 ]

`[9, 1, 3, 5, 9, 3]` - this should be the result, but I get `[ 9, 1 ]` only. 
`[3, 5, 9, 3]` gets vanished.

EDIT:

It's kinda hard to get it, because I use only variables.

```
byte[] bb = new byte[] { 0x46, 0xEE, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x43, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x63, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x31, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x47, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x20, 0x46, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x75, 0x6D, 0x32, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x53, 0x75, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x74, 0x33, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x4C, 0x65, 0x61, 0x76, 0x65, 0x2D, 0x40, 0x29, 0x0E, 0x02, 0x0F, 0x02, 0x07 };

byte[] torp = new byte[] { 0x46, 0xEE, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x43, 0x68, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x63, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x49, 0x6E, 0x66, 0x6F, 0x31, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x47, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x20, 0x46, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x75, 0x6D, 0x32, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x53, 0x75, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x74, 0x33, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x4C, 0x65, 0x61, 0x76, 0x65, 0x2D, 0x40 };

byte[] newbb = bb.Except(torp).ToArray();
```

Result should be: `{ 0x29, 0x0E, 0x02, 0x0F, 0x02, 0x07 }` but I get only `{ 0x29, 0x0F }`

For example there is a text: iamdancinginlava. I want to remove dancing. Result should be: iaminlava.

Comment: please show your exact code.

Comment: There is nothing to show actually.
newbb = bb.Except(mg.returnBytes()).ToArray();

Comment: `var a = new List<byte> { 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 5, 9, 3 }.Except(new List<byte> { 4, 6, 8 })` yields `9, 1, 3, 5`, not only `9` and `1`. Problem is coming from something that you did not show. Please paste the smallest code example that you can that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CommanderShepard only you and really good telepaths know how `bb`, `mg`, and `returnBytes` are defined in your code. You need to give the rest of us something to work with if you want help.

Comment: People come on Stackoverflow because they need help getting some of their code to work. Experienced programmers gather together to look at your code and sometimes they can spot the problem immediately. Other times, they plug the code into their compiler, debug it and spend a little time on trying to figure out the problem. When you don't post any code though, it makes it real hard to spot the problem in your code or debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something by myself.
It looks dirty, but I solved my problem with it.

```
internal static int[] Locate(this byte[] self, byte[] candidate)
{
    if (IsEmptyLocate(self, candidate))
        return null;

    var list = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < self.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!IsMatch(self, i, candidate))
            continue;

        list.Add(i);
    }

    return list.Count == 0 ? null : list.ToArray();
}

static bool IsMatch(byte[] array, int position, byte[] candidate)
{
    if (candidate.Length > (array.Length - position))
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate.Length; i++)
        if (array[position + i] != candidate[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}

static bool IsEmptyLocate(byte[] array, byte[] candidate)
{
    return array == null
        || candidate == null
        || array.Length == 0
        || candidate.Length == 0
        || candidate.Length > array.Length;
}
internal static byte[] trimArray(byte[] man, byte[] remove)
{
    try
    {
        int seekp = Program.Locate(man, remove)[0];
        if (seekp > 0)
        {
            byte[] pr = new byte[seekp];
            Array.Copy(man, 0, pr, 0, seekp);

            byte[] aa = new byte[man.Length - seekp];

            Array.Copy(man, seekp, aa, 0, man.Length - seekp);
            man = aa;

            byte[] hm = new byte[man.Length - remove.Length];
            Array.Copy(man, seekp + remove.Length, hm, 0, hm.Length);
            return hm;
        }

        byte[] hm = new byte[man.Length - remove.Length];
        Array.Copy(man, seekp + remove.Length, hm, 0, hm.Length);
        return hm;
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        return new byte[] { };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Except does not care about order of items or repetitions. 0x02, 0x0f and 0x07 all show up in `torp` so they where removed from the result.

Also Except uses a `HashSet<T>` to perform the operation, so had you had multiple 0x29 or 0x0E you would only get one in the result. Imagine there is a implicit `.Distinct()` on the output after all of the items from the except list were removed.

Comment: Well you never told us what your task is so its kind of hard to tell you how to accomplish it.

Comment: I want to remove one byte array from another. With order of course.

Comment: So if I had `0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04` and my "removal array" was `0x02, 0x03` what output would you expect? Also if I had `0x02, 0x03, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04` and the removal array was `0x02, 0x03` what output would you expect?

Comment: 1) 0x01, 0x04
2) All my arrays are unique and there are no same occurrences.
But of course if that would happen, then result should be only 0x04.
I just want to remove byte array from byte array. -> Find where it is and then cut it out. Result should contain what's left in that array, excluding "removal array".

Comment: For example there is a text: iamdancinginlava.
I want to remove dancing. Result should be: iaminlava.

Comment: Good, now ask a new question showing what you tried, what you get out, and what you wanted to get out. including the details and examples.

Comment: The problem is I can't post another question that fast.

Comment: Take the time to write up a good question with plently of details then and post when you can.